# Dart Inline type definition

Tags: dart

With **TypeScript**, I can do this:

```
export class Ticket extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    //...

    clientEndUtils: {
        maxBuyableQtyForCurrentBuyer: number;
    }/* THIS IS INLINE TYPE DEFINITION */

}
```

Is there a way to do that with **Dart Language**?

I mean defining a type inside a class.

Comment: I don't know TypeScript very well, but you can define a type that is local to a library and visible only to members of that library (typically the same file, unless you also use part/partof).

Comment: it's not possible in dart until now.